# Linear Mixed Model in lme4 package- estimate is correct magnitude but wrong direction

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, simpsons-paradox

I am using lmer in lme4 to do linear mixed modeling. I have simplified my model to just one fixed effect and one random effect to isolate the problem. I have a continuous DV (score), a dichotomous fixed effect (treatment), and a random variable (person). Each person took up to 12 tests over the course of 4 years, the use of the random variable is to account for any variability that is present due to relationships among each person's test scores.

Based on the raw data, the mean of the treatment group is 10 points lower than the control group. The estimate I am getting using lmer is showing treatment1 as having an estimate of 10, meaning that the treatment group is being estimated to be 10 points higher than the control. Any ideas why this might happen? Does this sound like an example of Simpson's paradox? I have quadruple-checked that the groups are coded correctly, it is not a case of flipping the 1's and 0's.

One other note- the treatment group is much smaller than the control group. I have 3770 in the treatment group and 145130 in the control group. Could this be the problem?

I'm not sure what code would be helpful to include, please let me know and I will add it!

Comment: When you say "the observed mean of the treatment group T" do you mean: a) the average of all test scores by people in the T group, or b) the average of the average personal test score by people in the T group?

Comment: @ dipetkov I mean the average of all test scores by people in the T group. This is a little complicated to answer however because some people are in the control group for some test events and the treatment group for others (ie they did not have treatment for the first six time points, and did for the last six).

Comment: You might discover more about what's happening by comparing these two ways to average test scores because some participants contribute few scores and others -- many scores (I gather from your problem description). PS: Details that are "a little complicated" are often important for getting a helpful answer. You should include all relevant information in the question, not in the comments. These are not read by everyone.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that and see what I find. I hadn't thought of looking at the raw data in that way.

Comment: The best option would be to provide some data, or simulated data that has the same structure & issues as your real data.